# In 1 Timothy 3:15 what is the function of a "στύλος καὶ ἑδραίωμα τῆς ἀληθείας"?

Tags: greek, word-study, 1-timothy

> NIV 1 Timothy 3:15 if I am delayed, you will know how people ought to
>   conduct themselves in God's household, which is the church of the
>   living God, **the pillar and foundation of the truth.**
>
> WH ἐὰν δὲ βραδύνω, ἵνα εἰδῇς πῶς δεῖ ἐν οἴκῳ θεοῦ ἀναστρέφεσθαι, ἥτις
>   ἐστὶν ἐκκλησία θεοῦ ζῶντος, στύλος καὶ ἑδραίωμα τῆς ἀληθείας·

I see this is usually translated "pillar and foundation" or similar implying that the truth is supported (held up) by the assembly. The word "foundation" seems to suggest that the truth "rests on" the assembly. But to my mind this is entirely backward since the assembly rests on the truth. As Paul said:

> NIV Romans 3:4
>
> Not at all! Let God be true, and every human being a liar. As it is
>   written: "So that you may be proved right when you speak and prevail
>   when you judge."

Might the "pillar and foundation" be "the pillar and base"? In other words, the base rests on the ground (which is the foundation) and the pillar rests on the base and the truth is thus lifted up and put on display in the assembly. In other words, would one speak of the display of a bust resting on a "pillar and base" to enhance its beauty rather than to in some way be responsible for maintaining truth?

### Update

Ellicott uses "display" terminology: https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/1_timothy/3.htm

Answer (score 1):

The question is, what was Paul referring to when he used this metaphor, the pillar and ground (foundation) of the truth, as the household of God?

I take a somewhat unique approach to this passage, placing its meaning in the context of the place where Timothy was serving as pastor.  Timothy was a struggling pastor in Ephesus and 1 Timothy was intended to inform Timothy and the church.  If you recall the most dominant feature both physically and culturally within Ephesus was the temple of Diana, which was one of the seven wonders of the ancient world.  It was famous for its 127 pillars, some of which were covered in gold and jewels; and also for the foundations.  Pliny, an ancient source speaks of the wonders of both the columns and the foundations of that temple.

Serving in Ephesus had to be a difficult thing since this pagan temple literally dominated everything you did and saw in that city.  It was with that in mind that Paul made reference to those two metaphors in reference to the church. the pillar and ground of the truth.  In the context Paul also makes it clear that it is in the church, the people, that is the house of God. Again I think Paul was contrasting this with the wicked temple on the hill.

**If it is to be taken metaphorically as a comparison with the temple of Diana then it would be wrong to look to much into the details of the words and instead focus on what they assert, namely, that the Church as the house of God is the source of truth and not some pagan temple.**

When Paul says 1 Tim 3:14 that "I write these things," I think he was referring to the whole letter and not just to the preceding context of the qualifications of bishop.

It is very helpful to compare this to Acts 19 where Paul first comes to Ephesus.

Comment: I would probably see it more that Paul is using an image of the temple but that the Diana temple would inevitably loom large in the imagination as the "other" temple but yes, good observation. +1

Comment: Ellicott mentions the Ephesian temple:  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/1_timothy/3.htm

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

In contemplating Revelation's letter to the Gatherings I noticed the link between the Gatherings and candelabras:

> [Rev 2:1-7 ESV] (1) "To the angel of the church in Ephesus write: 'The words of him who holds the seven stars in his right hand, who walks among the seven golden lampstands. (2) "'I know your works, your toil and your patient endurance, and how you cannot bear with those who are evil, but have tested those who call themselves apostles and are not, and found them to be false. (3) I know you are enduring patiently and bearing up for my name's sake, and you have not grown weary. (4) But I have this against you, that you have abandoned the love you had at first. (5) Remember therefore from where you have fallen; repent, and do the works you did at first. If not, I will come to you and remove your lampstand from its place, unless you repent. (6) Yet this you have: you hate the works of the Nicolaitans, which I also hate. (7) He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. To the one who conquers I will grant to eat of the tree of life, which is in the paradise of God.'

It seems to me that these "lamp stands" are the proper idea. That is, their duty is to lift up the flame in order to give light to the whole "house":

> [Mat 5:14-16 ESV] (14) "You are the light of the world. A city set on a hill cannot be hidden. (15) Nor do people light a lamp and put it under a basket, but on a stand, and it gives light to all in the house. (16) In the same way, let your light shine before others, so that they may see your good works and give glory to your Father who is in heaven.

However, if they are unfaithful in doing so the truth does not collapse but they will be removed as light bearers.

### Original Answer

Okay, in my pursuit for a better understanding of Paul's metaphor of a "pillar and base of the truth" I found [Clarke](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/barnes/1_timothy/3.htm) particularly satisfying:

> ...To do this, he reminded him that the truth of God - that revealed truth which he had given to save the world - was entrusted to the church; that it was designed to preserve it pure, to defend it, and to transmit it to future times; and that, therefore, every one to whom the administration of the affairs of the church was entrusted, should engage in this duty with a deep conviction of his responsibility. On the construction of the passage, Bloomfield Rosenmuller, and Clarke, may be consulted. **The word "pillar" means a column, such as that by which a building is supported, and then any firm prop or support; Galatians 2:9; Revelation 3:12. If it refers to the church here, it means that that is the support of the truth, as a pillar is of a building. It sustains it amidst the war of elements, the natural tendency to fall, and the assaults which may be made on it, and preserves it when it would otherwise tumble into ruin.**
>
> Thus it is with the church. **It is entrusted with the business of maintaining the truth, of defending it from the assaults of error, and of transmitting it to future times. The truth is, in fact, upheld in the world by the church. The people of the world feel no interest in defending it, and it is to the church of Christ that it is owing that it is preserved and transmitted from age to age**. The word rendered **"ground" - ἑδραίωμα hedraiōma - means, properly, a basis, or foundation. The figure here is evidently taken from architecture, as the use of the word pillar is. The proper meaning of the one expression would be, that truth is supported by the church. as an edifice is by a pillar; of the other, that the truth rests "on" the church, as a house does on its foundation. It is that which makes it fixed, stable, permanent; that on which it securely stands amidst storms and tempests; that which renders it firm when systems of error are swept away as a house that is built on the sand; compare notes on Matthew 7:24-27.**
>
> **The meaning then is, that the stability of the truth on earth is dependent on the church. It is owing to the fact that the church is itself founded on a rock, that the gates of hell cannot prevail against it, that no storms of persecution can overthrow it, that the truth is preserved from age to age.** Other systems of religion are swept away; other opinions change; other forms of doctrine vanish; but the knowledge of the great system of redemption is preserved on earth unshaken, because the church is preserved, and because its foundations cannot be moved. **This does not refer, I suppose, to creeds and confessions, or to the decisions of synods and councils; but to the living spirit of truth and piety "in" the church itself.** As certainly as the church continues to live, so certain it will be that the truth of God will be perpetuated among people.